# using membership in azure mobile services .net backend

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to build a mobile service using an existing code .net backend.
I use membership to authenticate users. 
When I upload the code to azure mobile services i get an error

> Exception=System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\MobileServicesDotNet\1.0.447\App_Data' is denied.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
>      at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
>      at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String connectionString)
>      at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
>      at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetUserNameByEmail(String email)
>      at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(String emailToMatch)

yet in my web config ( which is the same for my web application and its working) i define the database connection string name ( i also tried the connection string and it didnt work as well).

Any idea how to make azure mobile service to work with membership?

My connection string is connected azure sql database and not local db.

thanks

Comment: you are using a connection string to a local database based in a local database....

Comment: update the exception also then. Because this exception will *not* happen with Connection string to Azure SQL Database. Or you are missusing Connection string - make sure your Membership uses the correct connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Provide a valid connection string to Azure SQL Database and not (local) or SQLExpress connection string that tries to create local database file in App_Data folder.

When working with any service in Azure (except Virtual Machines) it is really, really bad idea to use default connection strings that point to (local) or SQLExpress instances and want to create database file in local folder. Always consider using Azure SQL Database, or a SQL Server deployed in Azure VM (or on-premises)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are using the connection string defined in the portal. If you use the default one, the local setting will be overridden by the portal when you publish. Go to the Configure tab for your mobile service in the Azure portal. Your Membership project needs to use the string MS_TableConnectionString that's in the "connection strings" section.